# Devise, can't use custom controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I followed the instructions given on [devise page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise). Only thing different is that I am customizing registrations and their example is on sessions.

When I hit `/users/sign_up` page, devise is using `Devise::RegistrationsController#new` action instead of `new` action from `users_controller.rb`

As you can see from the server log below, `XXXXXXXXXX\nxxxxxxxxxxx` is not seen, even though user controller has `new` action that `puts "XXXXXXXXXX\nxxxxxxxxxxx"`

```
Started GET "/users/sign_up" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-14 03:29:52 -0700
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
  Rendered /Users/jasonkim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/devise-2.1.2/app/views/devise/shared/_links.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered users/registrations/new.html.haml within layouts/application (4.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 88ms (Views: 12.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

### users_controller.rb

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    @user = User.new
    address = @user.address.build
    puts "XXXXXXXXXX\nxxxxxxxxxxx"
  end
end
```

### routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registration => "users/registration" }
devise_for :employers
```

### only thing i added in devise.rb

```
config.scoped_views = true
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrationS => "users/registrationS" }
```

with a trailing 's' (but of course in lower case)

Comment: I also had to change the name of the controller file from `users_controller.rb` to `users/registrations_controller.rb`